# The "drupal" tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, migration

I just noticed a few questions had been tagged with "drupal." This really seems pointless to tag a question with drupal, since all questions that can't be tagged with "drupal" would be off-topic.

I deleted them all, but if questions are going to be migrated from StackOverflow, we will need to remember to tidy them up, as almost all of those would be tagged "drupal."

Comment: The tag is now blocked; every migrated questions will not contain that tag, once they are migrated on _Drupal Answers_.

Comment: I am closing this question as it is not relevant anymore.

Answer (score 2):

[This kind of tag is automatically removed during migration for some sites already](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/512/kill-the-unix-tag/514#514). I assume that once Drupal.SE graduates this will also be implemented for the site.

Comment: It is removed if the tag is blocked, as it happens now with _drupal_, that has been added to the blocked tag list.

Comment: No need to wait for graduation.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, tagging a question with [drupal](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drupal) doesn't have any meaning on drupal.SE; if the question is not about a Drupal version, then the tag should not be used.

Apart in questions migrated from other SE sites (including SO), the tag could be used from a user that doesn't know which other tags should use; in most of the case, there is surely another tag that can be used for the question, or a new tag can be created.